# How does a Watt (1mW from a laser) relate to Amps (20mA max current rating for collector of a phototransistor)?

Tags: laser, phototransistor

How does a Watt (1mW from a lasermodule) relate to Amps (20mA max current rating for collector of a phototransistor) ?

I want to know if the 1mW output from the laser is within or outside the range of what the phototransistor can deal with (20mA max)
Laser is powered of a 5V circuit.

Comment: Doesn't that depend on how much laser light hits the phototransistor? 5V * 20mA = 0.1Watts

Comment: You can externally limit the current to the phototransistor (for example with a resistor). 1mW is a lot of light if it's focused on the tiny die (often they're spec'd at 1mW/cm^2).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, in my application area, 1 mW incident on a 50-um diameter photodetector (~2x10^(-3) cm^2) is not out of line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When light strikes a semiconductor photodetector, each photon absorbed in the active region generates a free  carrier pair (an electron and a hole). These carriers are swept out of the active region and form the *photocurrent* of the receiver. Some types of devices, like phototransistors and avalanche photodiodes, have an additional gain mechanism so that the initially generated photocurrent is multiplied by a gain factor.

The fraction of the incident photons that stimulate useful photocurrent is called the *quantum efficiency*, usually denoted as \$\eta\$.

The overall ratio of output current to incident optical power is the *responsivity*, *R*.

The responsivity can be expressed as

\$R=M\eta{}\dfrac{e}{h\nu}\$,

where *M* is the gain, *e* is the fundamental charge,  \$h\nu\$ is the photon energy.

Now the relation between optical input power, \$P\$, and photodetector current is

\$I = RP\$.

For practical problems, you need to look at the datasheet of your phototransistor, which is likely to have a characteristic curve similar to this to indicate the responsivity:

[image]