# Avalanche Photodiode Current Gain

Tags: current, datasheet, light, photodiode

I'm designing a readout circuit for an APD manifactured by Hamamatsu Photonics ([datasheet](http://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/s12572-025_etc_kapd1043e03.pdf)). However, I've found myself lacking some information about exactly how would the device behave in my particular application. The datasheet supplies the gain *M*, the dark count and photon detection efficiency, but no information whatsoever about leakage and noise current, so I am unable to extrapolate what kind of current characteristics the device has. Particularly when constructing a transimpedance amplifier, I'd need to have an idea of the photodiode current at a specific light level (my goal is to work at low to no light) - how exactly could I find that out from the datasheet?

Comment: Doesn't the dark count tell you something about the noise - I'm presuming these are "false" counts?

Comment: I assume the dark current is proportional to these "dark counts" - but that doesn't imply how much mA are flowing through the detector, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it does. This photodiode works by having a detected photon kick loose an electron, which then undergoes an avalanche amplification with an amplification factor M. So each dark count produces (on average) M electrons. Multiply by the dark count rate and you have the dark current in electrons. Noise in these devices is a complex subject, and you need to do some research outside the data sheet to understand it.

Comment: Stuck at a rather trivial conversion, but how would one convert number of electrons/charge to amps (is there a thing as a tabulated electron speed?)

Comment: Obviously the question should rather be: can the speed of light be used in such a conversion? I think so, but I'm not sure

Comment: @joaocandre, see my recent [answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108950/how-does-a-watt-1mw-from-a-laser-relate-to-amps-20ma-max-current-rating-for-c/108952#108952) on this subject. That question was about a phototransistor, but the responsivity formula for an APD is the same, even if the gain mechanism is different.

Comment: If you're actually working in a photon-counting regime, you need to think in terms of impulses: energy in (h x nu) results in charge out (cuolombs). There should be no speed-of-light term. The frequency response of the detector will shape the pulse and have a strong effect on the peak output current.

Comment: joaocandre - go find how many electrons per coulomb. One ampere current is one coulomb per second.

Comment: @ThePhoton thank you for the answer but I'm still unable to get the rated current, because I would the incident photon power - which I assume to be null when considering the dark current of a photodiode. I can compute the incident *energy* of a single photon, but that is not the same thing as the incident power *P*