# How to find linear LEDs (light power(mW) vs current)?

Tags: led, linear

I'm looking to use an LED in a control application.
(feedback via LED to photodiode.)

I found a few questions that didn't fit.

- [Adjustable linear led driver? Linear, not PWM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19876/adjustable-linear-led-driver-linear-not-pwm).
- [Light intensity and photodiode current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/302663/light-intensity-and-photodiode-current).

I'd like to make it all linear, no PWM.
(I worry about the led turn on/off time with PWM, I can average, but that's slower.  Even with pwm having a linear 'current' control knob might help.)

What frequency you ask?; I guess 1-10 MHz, for a start, but faster
is better. :)  I dream of finding an LED whose light output (in mW) is linear 
with current, from say 1 uA to 1 mA.  Is there some search phrase I can look for?  Searching for leds on the web is a fire house. 
I know this is kinda a shopping question, Is there a meta-shopping type 
question?  How to shop?

Let me edit: Yes a linear opto-coupler would be even better. If it was 
fast.  > 1MHz.

Comment: XY problem. http://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/AN-107.pdf/$file/AN-107.pdf

Comment: I think you are looking for "Linear Opto-couplers" example http://www.vishay.com/docs/83622/il300.pdf. Those have dual matched detectors. You use one on the primary side in the feedback loop. See the examples in the data sheet.

Comment: do you actually need linearly controlled light somewhere or only a linear optocoupled signal path?

Comment: How linear is your "linear"? Generally, light output is nearly linear with current in all LEDs. I think this thread can give you few angles on the subject, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/17528/117785

Comment: @τεκ, that would be nice if faster.

Comment: @AliChen, thanks I'll look at kingbright.  how linear? I want to use in a photodiode TIA instead of feedback R.  I'll do a current drive for the led but the more linear the better.

Comment: I have never measured light output at low currents such as 1uA, but I have measured backlight brightness over a range of around 1mA to 20mA or so, and found it to be linear enough that any nonlinearity was lost in the uncertainty of my luminance meter. I seem to remember that LED's have a "knee" somewhere where they become less linear or the slope changes. But I think that is at a higher current, far above 1mA.

Comment: I think there is also a way to linearize the light by adding a second sensor on the same side of the board as the LED.

Comment: From experience: buy 1000 LEDs from a single batch from a single supplier then only about 50 of them will be stable -- if you hold them at a stable temperature and feed them a very stable current. They will still need to be calibrated. But a few will be stable. The others you might as well throw in the garbage can. (This includes the use of a calibrated Keithley 6221 for accurate currents.) LEDs just drift. I don't think 'stability' or 'precision' of light output relative to current input is on any spec sheet. Will be interested in what you find. (Three orders of linearity? Hah.)

Comment: @jonk, I'm not sure why only 50 are useful.  A little drift in output should be OK.  It's in a feedback loop.

Answer (score 1):

Since Diodes and transistor hFE are both inherently non-linear , one way to make it ultralinear is to use a dual version and compensate one side using linear error correction feedback on the other side( sophisticated method).

Optoisolators are inherently nonlinear may have a  3:1 gain tolerance in output range for any input current. Expecting a linear response on anything more requires expertise in the secondary opto loop using error correction with an Op Amp.

> One needs to have reasonable specs and tolerances for linearity and bandwidth then solve the technical issues.  Since you have neither no rational solution can be given, other than a book on opto linear design.

LED  dynamic range may be up to 3 decades but very non-linear  and bandwidth constraints are severe.

- 1st you need a voltage to current feedback converter with OA
- 2nd  you need a 2ndary transfer function error correction circuit design with low gain. (<1)

### EDIT

Fortunately the experts in opto design Sharp (now licensed to Vishay) have such a [solution](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83622/il300.pdf) with dual emitters (LED) for high gain linearity and stability.

- 0.01 % servo linearity
- Wide bandwidth, > 200 kHz
- High gain stability, ± 0.005 %/°C typically

  > Detectors are very stable and low error and well matched while Emitters are high deviation thus only 1 emitter uses 2 detectors, 1 for voltage to current feedback and the other detector for output to current to voltage sense resistive load.

Comment: I don't know why LED's should be inherently non-linear (with current drive).  But in practice I agree they are.  The compensation trick for the LED is something I'll think about.  I'd like to do something like this... http://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.4931042   Note: they compensate for the LED non-linearity by using a 3rd TIA for the output.